# How is the formula for the entropy of the lognormal distribution derived?

Tags: probability, distributions, entropy, lognormal-distribution

Wikipedia gives the [*entropy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) of the lognormal distribution in nats as
$$\mu + \frac{1}{2} \ln(2\pi e \sigma^2)$$  Can anyone point me to a derivation of this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z$ be standard normal, so that $X=e^{\mu+\sigma Z}$ is log-normal. By definition of differential entropy,
$$
h(X)=-\mathbb E[\log f(X)],\quad \text{where}\quad f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma x\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[-\frac{(\log x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right].
$$
(Of course, $f(x)$ is the density of a log-normal random variable.) Now observe that
$$
f(X)=\frac{1}{\sigma X\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-Z^2/2},
$$
so that
$$
-\log f(X)=\frac{Z^2}{2}+\log(\sigma X\sqrt{2\pi})=\frac{Z^2}{2}+\log(\sigma \sqrt{2\pi})+\mu+\sigma Z.
$$
Since $Z$ is standard normal, $\mathbb EZ=0$ and $\mathbb EZ^2=1$. Therefore
$$
h(X)=\frac{1}{2}+\log(\sigma \sqrt{2\pi})+\mu,
$$
which matches the formula upon simple algebraic manipulation.