# Differential entropy of a multivariate log-normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, entropy, lognormal-distribution, information-theory

Let $Y$ be a multivariate log-normal random variable. As such, $\ln(Y)$ follows a multivariate normal distribution, which I denote by $\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$. I already know the normal distribution parameters ($\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$), and I can calculate the mean and covariance matrix of the log-normal distribution with the appropriate equations ([like the ones shown on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Multivariate_log-normal)).

**Question**: How can I obtain the differential entropy of the multivariate log-normal distribution? Is the differential entropy of the corresponding normal distribution equivalent? If so, I could use this formula to calculate it:

$$ H(Y) = \frac{1}{2}\ln{(2\pi e)^N\det{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}}  $$

where $N$ is the dimensionality of the multivariate distributions.

Conceptually, the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) is the "measure of average surprisal of a random variable [following a continuous probability distribution]". My reasoning is that converting a normal distribution to a log-normal one (and vice-versa) does not add or remove information. Therefore, the entropy of the log-normal distribution should remain the same as that of the corresponding normal distribution. Is that correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, the logarithmic change of variable carries with it the need to introduce its Jacobian, which will change the differential entropy.  Thus it would be a surprise to find that $H(Y)$ and $H(\log Y)$ are the same.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411171 for the lognormal entropy (in the univariate case).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I saw that question you linked, but I can't find anything about the entropy of the multivariate log-normal distribution. It must have been already derived in some old obscure textbook...

Comment: I believe that answer generalizes, using exactly the same methods used for the Normal distribution.